# Чтение строки произвольной длины из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Мне нужно написать функцию чтения строки из файла с соблюдением следующих условий

- строка должна читаться целиком за один проход до символа EOF или EOL
- нельзя заранее выделять большой буфер, в который гарантировано поместится читаемая строка нельзя
- `realloc()` использовать нельзя

Ничего лучше, кроме того как читать посимвольно и пихать в стек, не придумал. Есть ли еще какие-нибудь варианты? Может быть с использованием `string.h`?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47699/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-kharatyan------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например. `LIST_ITEM_SIZE` - максимально допустимый размер буфера.

```
size_t read_line( list *storage, FILE *file ) 
{
    char buf[LIST_ITEM_SIZE];
    size_t size = 0;
    while( fgets( buf, sizeof(buf)-1, file ) ) {
        size_t readed = strlen(buf);
        add_to_list( storage, buf, readed );
        size += readed;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Хотя, конечно, проще сначала выделить небольшой буфер и по мере чтения растягивать его при помощи `malloc()`/`strcpy()`.

Comment: omg, прочитайте условие пожалуйста еще раз

Comment: Прочитал. Ни одного противоречия не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

1. mmap
2. выделить один буфер, равный или кратный размеру блока ввода/вывода файловой системы, типичный размер 4К, и использовать его для хранения данных. Посмотреть не имеет ли API вашей ОС возможности работать по callbackу -- чтобы ОС по окончании чтения в буфер дергала вашу собственную функцию анализа `CALLBACK parser(char*);`, полезно для "плавности" работы в многозадачных ОС. Если нет, реализовать обычный цикл чтения `while not EOF { os_read(buf); parse(buf); }`